# In Python, how to concisely get nested values in json data?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have data loaded from JSON and am trying to extract arbitrary nested values *using a list as input*, where the list corresponds to the *names of successive children*. I want a function *get_value(data,lookup)* that returns the value from data by treating each entry in *lookup* as a nested child.

In the example below, when `lookup=['alldata','TimeSeries','rates']`, the return value should be `[1.3241,1.3233]`.

```
json_data = {'alldata':{'name':'CAD/USD','TimeSeries':{'dates':['2018-01-01','2018-01-02'],'rates':[1.3241,1.3233]}}}

def get_value(data,lookup):
    res = data
    for item in lookup:
        res = res[item]
    return res

lookup = ['alldata','TimeSeries','rates']
get_value(json_data,lookup)
```

My example works, but there are two problems:

1. <s>It's **inefficient** - In my *for loop*, I copy the whole TimeSeries object to *res*, only to then replace it with the rates list.</s> As @Andrej Kesely explained, *res* is a reference at each iteration, so data isn't being copied.
2. It's **not concise** - I was hoping to be able to find a concise (eg one or two line) way of extracting the data using something like list comprehension syntax

Comment: It looks good to me, why do you think it's inefficient? You aren't copying anything in the loop, the `res` variable holds only reference to object.

Comment: @AndrejKesely - thanks, I didn't realize that res was a reference, but just confirmed it with `res = json_data; res = res['alldata']; print(json_data['alldata'] is res)`. This means that inefficiency isn't an issue, only conciseness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one-liner and you are using Python 3.8, you can use assignment expression (*"walrus operator"*):

```
json_data = {'alldata':{'name':'CAD/USD','TimeSeries':{'dates':['2018-01-01','2018-01-02'],'rates':[1.3241,1.3233]}}}

def get_value(data,lookup):
    return [data:=data[item] for item in lookup][-1]

lookup = ['alldata','TimeSeries','rates']
print( get_value(json_data,lookup) )
```

Prints:

```
[1.3241, 1.3233]
```

Comment: This looks clever - thanks! I'm not using python 3.8, but will note this for when I upgrade. I've just added an extension to the original question to define replace_value() (or should I be posting a new question? [I'm relatively new to StackOverflow])

Comment: @maurera Better close this question (approve answer that you like most) and write new one :) And welcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: Done. Extension moved to [In Python, how to concisely replace nested values in json data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59584603/11918892)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it without a loop, but you could use a reducer here to increase readability.

```
functools.reduce(dict.get, lookup, json_data)
```

Comment: This is concise - thanks! I was hoping to have it concise without an import statement, but this doesn't appear possible

Comment: Python3 transition still messing me up a bit, `reduce` used to be primitive I think.