# In Python, how to concisely replace nested values in json data?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

This is an extension to [In Python, how to concisely get nested values in json data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59583518/11918892)

I have data loaded from JSON and am trying to replace arbitrary nested values *using a list as input*, where the list corresponds to the names of *successive children*. I want a function **replace_value(data,lookup,value)** that replaces the value in the data by treating each entry in lookup as a nested child.

Here is the structure of what I'm trying to do:

```
json_data = {'alldata':{'name':'CAD/USD','TimeSeries':{'dates':['2018-01-01','2018-01-02'],'rates':[1.3241,1.3233]}}}

def replace_value(data,lookup,value):
    DEFINITION

lookup = ['alldata','TimeSeries','rates']
replace_value(json_data,lookup,[2,3])

# The following should return [2,3]
print(json_data['alldata']['TimeSeries']['rates'])
```

I was able to make a start with get_value(), but am stumped about how to do replacement. I'm not fixed to this code structure, but want to be able to programatically replace a value in the data given the list of successive children and the value to replace.

**Note: it is possible that *lookup* can be of length 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the lookups until we're second from the end, then assign the value to the last lookup in the current object

```
def get_value(data,lookup):  # Or whatever definition you like
    res = data
    for item in lookup:
        res = res[item]
    return res

def replace_value(data, lookup, value):
    obj = get_value(data, lookup[:-1])
    obj[lookup[-1]] = value

json_data = {'alldata':{'name':'CAD/USD','TimeSeries':{'dates':['2018-01-01','2018-01-02'],'rates':[1.3241,1.3233]}}}

lookup = ['alldata','TimeSeries','rates']
replace_value(json_data,lookup,[2,3])

print(json_data['alldata']['TimeSeries']['rates']) # [2, 3]
```

If you're worried about the list copy `lookup[:-1]`, you can replace it with an [iterator slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

def replace_value(data, lookup, value):
    it = iter(lookup)
    slice = islice(it, len(lookup)-1)
    obj = get_value(data, slice)
    final = next(it)
    obj[final] = value
```

Comment: Hi @PatrickHaugh what if you don't really know all the lookup? If the json is big and full of childrens and you only know that there is a 'rates' somewhere that needs changing?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the parent to the final sub-dict first, so that you can reference it to alter the value of that sub-dict under the final key:

```
def replace_value(data, lookup, replacement):
    *parents, key = lookup
    for parent in parents:
        data = data[parent]
    data[key] = replacement
```

so that:

```
json_data = {'alldata':{'name':'CAD/USD','TimeSeries':{'dates':['2018-01-01','2018-01-02'],'rates':[1.3241,1.3233]}}}
lookup = ['alldata','TimeSeries','rates']
replace_value(json_data,lookup,[2,3])
print(json_data['alldata']['TimeSeries']['rates'])
```

outputs:

```
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have `get_value`

```
get_value(json_data, lookup[:-1])[lookup[-1]] = value
```